# HTML Fields in opensagres

Tags: java, odt

I have to create a an `.odt` document from a template with fields. I am using opensagres, but when I tried to include a field with HTML content (created with editor of Primefaces), it is showed with HTML marks.

```
FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();
metadata.load("r", SgRequerimiento.class, true);
metadata.addFieldAsTextStyling("field", SyntaxKind.Html,false);
```

I also have tried with several SyntaxKind, and true/false.

Comment: Please, tell us, what is the expected result or behaviour.

Comment: When I tried to include an HTML content, I expect that it is included formatted without marks. For example, if content in HTML filed is <p>Hello</p> I expect it is shown as "Hello".